# originalModel/object always updating even after variable Initialization

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

hello currently I am trying to populate a default model for originalModel to store the original values. the issue i'm running into is this originalModel keeps updating even after I initialized it and i have no idea why here is the only time I initialize value.

```
export abstract class RequestBaseComponent{  
    protected abstract get model(): FaspRequest; //the subClass populates this via Input()
    originalModel: FaspRequest;

    constructor(    private formBuilder: FormBuilder 
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
     this.originalModel = this.model;
     this.setupForm();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is a reference issue. When you do `this.originalModel = this.model;` , you are actually storing the reference of `this.model` in `this.originalModel`. So when `this.model` is updated, `this.orginalModel` will be updated.

try this

```
this.originalModel = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.model));
```